# Extract tag text from line BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Recently I've been working on a scraping project. I'm kinda new to it, but could manage to do almost everything, but I'm having trouble with a little issue. I captured every line of a news article doing this:

```
lines=bs.find('div',{'class':'Text'}).find_all('div')
```

But for some reason, there's some lines that contain an `h2` tag and a `br` tag, like this one:

```
 <div><div><h2>Header2</h2></div><div><br/></div><div>Paragraph text
```

So if I run `.text` on that snippet I get "Header2Paragraph text". I've got the "Header2" text stored in other line, so I want to delete this second apparition.

I managed to isolate those lines doing this:

```
for n,t in enumerate(lines):
    if t.find('h2') is not None and t.find('br') is not None:
        print('\n',n,':',t)
```

But I don't know how to erase the text associated to the `h2` tag, so those lines become "Paragraph text" instead of "Header2Paragraph text". What can I do? Thanks

Comment: There's something missing in your html snippet; can you check and repost?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.get_text(split=' ')` instead of `.text` and you get text with space `"Header2 Paragraph text"`

You can also use different char - ie. "|" - `.get_text(split='|')` and you get `"Header2|Paragraph text"`.

And then you can use `split("|")` to get list `["Header2", "Paragraph text"]` and keep last element.

---

You can also find `h2` and `clear()` or `extract()` this tag and later you can get text from all `div`and you get without `"Header2"`

---

Documentation: [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text), [clear()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#clear), [extract()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract)